# How can I increase the memory allocated to one Azure web application in a given App Service Plan

Tags: .net, azure

I have several Azure web apps (dotnet 2.0 web api) living in an App Service Plan.  One of these apps would benefit from having more memory available.  How do I configure Azure to allow this; or is it something done on the dotnet side?